# Using phpseclib via resource of type (SSH2 SFTP)

Tags: phpseclib

I'm working on an intranet application for a company that need to do some actions on SFTP servers.
So, i want to use phpseclib because i need complex functions like rawlist, lstat...
My problem is that i don't have access to the host, or to the password.
I have only access to a function that return me a resoource of type (SSH2 Session).
I can obtain then a ressource of type (SSH2 SFTP) using php function ssh2_sftp. Basically, i want to use this ressource to connect to phpseclib. Is it possible (even if changement in constructor of phpseclib Net_SFTP are needed)? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

That, unfortunately, cannot be done. phpseclib implements SFTP by sending raw SSH2 packets. The libssh2 PECL extension that I gather you're using doesn't let programs send their own raw requests, hence phpseclib's being unusable with it.

I gather the server you're using is running a modified version of PHP with this `ssh2_return_resource()`-type function built into the binary already?